# MAP_DENYWRITE option of mmap was a source of denial-of-service attacks?

Tags: linux-kernel, posix

The man page of `mmap` function mentioned MAP_DENYWRITE can cause denial-of-service attacks. But why?

> **MAP_DENYWRITE** This flag is ignored.  (Long ago, it signaled that attempts to write to the underlying file should fail with ETXTBUSY. 
>   But this  was  a  source  of denial-of-service attacks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MAP_DENYWRITE` will lock the file and prevent other processes from writing it to it. Thus, it forms a basis for a Denial-of-Service (deny other processes from writing to the file).